# Calculating Zscore for multiple rows

Tags: t-sql

My table store measurement taken on several visits of a person. i want to calculate the zscore for each person.i notice my answer is not correct because is calculating for each row only.I want for each ID, the zscore on all four visits. below is what i have so far.

```
 `select ID,VNo1,VNo2,VNo3,VNo4
  .W1,AVG(W1) AS Mean , STDEVP(W1) AS StandardDeviation
    , STDEVP(W1) * STDEVP(W1) AS Zscore,

from dbo.measurement 
GROUP BY ID,VNo1,VNo2,VNo3,VNo4
```

`

Comment: Add the `GROUP BY ID` clause after your `FROM` and remove non-aggregate columns (except from `ID`) from your `SELECT` list. Is this SQL Server syntax?

Comment: @EzLo, i have edited my query, that is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what values do the `VNoX` columns hold, but if you have 1 row per visit then you just need to remove columns from your `GROUP BY`.

```
select 
    ID,
    AVG(W1) AS Mean ,
    STDEVP(W1) AS StandardDeviation,
    STDEVP(W1) * STDEVP(W1) AS Zscore,
from 
    dbo.measurement 
GROUP BY 
    ID
```